# Verbal Adjective of Necessity vs. Possibility

Tags: classical-latin, greek, verbs, adjective, gerundive

Greek distinguishes between verbal adjectives ending in -τέος and verbal adjectives ending in -τός. The latter (according to Smyth) express either possibility or the perfect passive participle (e.g. 'think*able*' or 'educated'), while the former express necessity in a way that is practically active in action (e.g. 'to-be-destroyed').

My question is this: does Latin have a similar distinction, or does the Gerundive do all the work of expressing *both* possibility and necessity? My hunch is that the Latin Gerundive does all the work, but then I am aware of words like 'expetibilis', where the suffix gives it a sense of possibility in the way the Greek -τός does (as 'desirable').

Thanks so much for any input you have!